# How to remove QueryString from url after being redirected by removing 'www' in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, model-view-controller

Ok, so I have a website built on a PHP MVC. First, I wanted to remove the 'www' from my domain URL, like this:

```
http://www.example.com/ -> http://example.com/
```

My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [B]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```

This is working fine, it redirects from www to non-www. But when I request:

```
http://www.example.com/Controller/Method/
```

Redirects to:

```
http://example.com/Controller/Method/?url=Controller%252fMethod%252f
```

It adds the QueryString and thats something I don't want, when the correct one must be:

```
http://example.com/Controller/Method/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a `?` to the end of the rewrite rule to strip the query string on redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [B]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The problem persist, still showing the correct URL with the QueryString

`http://example.com/Controller/Method/?url=Controller%252fMethod%252f`

Comment: You need to clear your browser cache. The 301 has cached it.